# Newly created alias should be activated constantly

Tags: command-line, bash, macos

I add an alias to `~/.bashrc and activate it.

```
    # add some helpful aliases
    alias l.='ls -d .* --color=auto'
```

Activate it

```
source .bashrc
```

It work well on current bash.

```
    $ l.
    ls: --color=auto: No such file or directory
    .   .cups   .python_history  ...
```

Unfortunately, it refuses to work when I quit and restart the bash

```
    $ l.
    -bash: l.: command not found
```

It has to be activated manually again.

```
  $ source .bashrc
  # then it works
    $ l.
    ls: --color=auto: No such file or directory
    .   .cups   .python_history  ...
```

What's the problem with my configuration?

Answer (score 3):

Terminal opens a login shell. The config file is .bash_profile!

You either have to source .bashrc in .bash_profile or add the alias to .bash_profile.

The proper alias would be: `alias l.='ls -dG .*'` (to get rid of `ls: --color=auto: No such file or directory`!